# How to remove a row by hitting delete key in QtableWidget?

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

I would like to delete a row of my Qtablewidget without adding a button and just by hitting the keyboard Delete key. I know, I need to use Key Events but not sure how to assign the even just to the specific tablewidget and the key event wouldnt be activated in the other sections where you have other tabs in the GUI (Long story short: key event just be dedicated to a specific table).

Push button delete style:

```
for i in rows:
                self.tableWidget.removeRow(i)
```

Attempt for Key Event:

```
QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete
QtGui.QTableWidget.keyPressEvent(...,...)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to subclass `QTableWidget` and implement your own `keyPressEvent`, e.g.

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets

class Main(QtWidgets.QTableWidget):

    def keyPressEvent(self, event):
        if event.key() == QtCore.Qt.Key_Delete:
            row = self.currentRow()
            self.removeRow(row)
        else:
            super().keyPressEvent(event)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = Main()

    main.setColumnCount(3)
    for i in range(4):
        main.insertRow(main.rowCount())
        for j in range(main.columnCount()):
            main.setItem(i, j, QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(f'row {i}, column{j}'))
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```